# Is there a way to to create a custom answering machine in android?

Tags: android

I'd like to create an app that allow you to filter incoming call to various answering message with :

- "this number is not available" for black listed phone numbers
- A formal message for strangers
- A informative message about what your doing for friends

I don't know how you can get automatically a call, play a recorded message then wait for the answer and record it. Or maybe there is just a way to interact with the actual answering system so I just have to plugin.

Any clue strongly appreciated. A human sacrifice for any code snippet :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access to the internal telephony is not possible or planned for future releases of Android:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e8904c82a2c4a333

This would present a security risk as app developers could intercept and hijack sensitive calls (eg. telephone banking)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible on the tmobile G1 at this time.  There is no way for an android SDK application to access the call input or output on this hardware/firmware combination.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d04c307973345fef/a628e578900b3dce?lnk=gst&q=dave+sparks+play+audio#a628e578900b3dce

and

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/185e33a3f420d1ac/e14e1dc84bb6dd24?lnk=gst&q=play+sound+call#e14e1dc84bb6dd24

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this answers the question, but it is somewhat related I think.

You can install Ultimate Voice Recorder which can record your conversations (very useful when calling customer 'service'). Since it can record it, it must have some way to access the conversation.

Also, the capabilities you have to give the app are quite scary (translated from dutch: full internet access, intercept outgoing calls, change preferences, call phone numbers directly, record audio/take pictures, update contacts, auto startup). It seems to me there must be something in there that can help you?

However, I don't think it can inject audio into the stream. The symbian version had an option to insert beeps into the conversation, but I don't think the android version has it.

http://www.fingertip-access.com/

Answer (score 2):

I have found out att for this use of your Phone Android or ISO, so far they ar decades behinde symbian and an inferior alternativ sadly, if you don't  install a custom kernel/jailbreak it's not possible to record incoming calls and screen them.     "Ultimate Voice Record ned you to use the phone in speaker mode."